# Why does intellisense fail on my F# script?

Tags: dll, f#, intellisense, query-expressions

I've been building a library to interact with one of my databases at work and everything is working fine. But when I open a new script and begin to use the library, it always freaks out when I try to use query expressions on the database. They work when I send them to F# interactive but the intellisense fails, drawing red lines under everything. Why is this? I would like my own dll to be the only thing a user would need to reference for a script.

[image]

`System.Data.Linq` is a reference in my dll file and I've set its `Copy Local` property to `True` to no avail. Other than that I haven't the faintest clue of what could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're showing in the screenshot is evidently an F# script (an `.fsx` file). Since the code that tries to access the table is in the script file, it is the script file that needs a reference to `System.Data.Linq`. The fact that your `AIXSupport.dll` library has the reference does not help: references do not "transfer" like that.

Simply add this one at the beginning of the script:

```
#r "System.Data.Linq"
```

Comment: Is it possible to compile `System.Data.Linq` inside of my own dll so that is not necessary?

Comment: Yes, there are tools for that. Take a look here: https://peteris.rocks/blog/merging-net-assemblies-with-msbuild/

Comment: @jks612 You could also distribute a .fsx containing all expected references alongside your dll. Users would then `#load “your.fsx”` instead of `#r “your.dll”`